# Problem running Facebook iphone DemoApp

Tags: iphone, facebook, button, authentication, safari

When I press on the Login button, i transfer to Safari, why?
I entered the app id as they asked. 
Whats wrong?

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of the Facebook iOS SDK uses a technique called Single Sign On (short: SSO). If your users don't have the Facebook App installed the framework will use Safari as a fallback method to authorize your application.

Answer (score 2):

@henrik is right, if you want to change this behavior, in Facebook.m, at about line 214, change line to

```
  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO];
```

if you do not want Facebook App auth, change as well :

```
  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

it will open the good old popup